# NUnit - SqlConnection timeout within Task

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout, task, nunit

I'm having this weird issue (or I think my brain is burned..). While I run this code from outside a Task, it works fine, but when I run within a Task.Run(() => ...), I get a SqlException timeout:

```
public static Item GetItemById(int id)
{
    Item result;

    using (var conn = App.DbFactory.CreateConnection())
    {
         result = _repository.GetById(id, conn) ?? throw new ElementNotFoundException();
    }
    
    return result;
}

// _repository.GetById
public Item GetById(int id, IDatabaseConnection conn)
{
     Item result;
        
     var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "QUERY COMMAND";

     using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) <-- EXCEPTION
     {
          result = dr.Read() ? Create(dr) : null;
     }

     return result;
}


// Method that works.
public static Item GetItemTest()
{
    return GetItemById(12);
}

// Method that doesn't work.
public static async Item GetItemAsyncTest()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => GetItemById(12));
}
```

App.DbFactory.CreateConnection() returns IDbConnection.

Update: The exception is thrown when executing the DbCommand (ExecuteReader).

The GeyById method only calls a repository method (raw TSQL query). The caller method is supposed to read each item from the database from a foreach (using Task/async/await, no more than 5 concurrent connections). At this point, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm missing some concept.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 and SQL Server 2012.

**Temp solution:**
Ok, I'd wasted almost 6hs trying to figure out what was wrong...and it was NUnit. When running GetItemAsyncTest() from a Test, it throws the timeout exception. Running the same async method from a Controller works like a charm.

I'm googling about this thing. If anyone had the same issue, I'll be glad to know what it is :)

Thanks!!

Comment: So you are running this piece of code through multiple tasks in parallel? That might mean you're exhausting the number of allowed active connections. Is the exception happening while establishing the connection or executing the query?

Comment: If you are running the same SQL code multiple times, you probably want to refactor it to do a single batch/joined operation

Comment: I’m running up to 5 connections at the same time (I don’t think that could be an issue). The exception is thrown while executing the command. It’s like the connection was blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally solved! It was a workaround between NUnit and TransactionScope. Testing an async method that hits the database using a TransactionScope (to keep the database clean) causes a timeout exception when executing the command.

The way to solve this issue was: *upgrade to NET Framework 4.5.1* and add *TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled* to the TransactionScope constructor.